# Replace different Values for multiple rows in excel

Tags: excel, replace, find

I have like 1k rows with value ‘n/a’,I want to replace the n/a with different values for different number of rows.say 250 n/a replaced with ‘IT’ ,250 n/a replaced with ‘Health’ ,250 n/a replaced with ‘Agric’ 250 n/a replaced with ‘Retail’.How can I specified the number of rows I want to replace in each category because if I used replace all.it will just replace the 1000 rows with a specified single value. Whereas I want to replace it into four categories.’Retail’,’Health,’Agric’,’IT’ each containing 250 rows.

I anticipate your help.Thank you.

I used find and replace,but it would change the 1000 rows at once except I find and replace one by one which would take a lot of time

Comment: If you select an area, Replace works only in the selected area. So if you select 250 rows, the replacemente will take place only in those 250 rows.

Comment: Thank you for your help,it works. Now in a case where I am working with like 500k rows how would you suggest I do this.

Comment: For 500k rows you'll need a helper column or a macro in VBA. You can add a column with an IF formula to replace values (something like `IF Targetcolumn=This Then return This` and overwrite original columns with helper column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you data has headers and you are starting in row 2:

```
=IF(ROW(A2)<252,"IT",IF(ROW(A2)<502,"Health",IF(ROW(A2)<752,"Retail",IF(ROW(A2)<1002,"Agric",""))))
```